# Changing font for integrals without errors

Tags: fonts, errors

So a while ago I wanted to change the font for my integrals, but not any other part of the font. What I ended up doing is just putting the following into my .sty file.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}
```

This does work, but I get 5 (essentially equivalent) error messages saying, e.g., "\iint already defined." The errors aren't exactly hurting anything---everything compiles just fine---but it would be nice to get rid of them and possibly learn something about TeX on the way. Does anyone know how to get rid of these error messages?

Thanks!

Edit: Below is an example of something that compiles but produces the aforementioned error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Different integral font
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}

\begin{document}

We say that a measurable function $f$ is of bounded mean oscillation if
\begin{align*}
    \|f\|_{BMO} := \sup_{B \text{ ball}} \left( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \inf_{a\in\mathbb{R}} \int_B |f - a| \, d\mu \right) < \infty .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Give a MWE from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please see how to produce a minimal, but working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/237192

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to load both `pxfonts` and `mathpazo`. Both will select their own version of Palatino for text and math and loading one after the other will override any of the fonts chosen by the first loaded one.

Besides, `pxfonts` suffers from really bad kerning in the math fonts and `mathpazo` is old and unmaintained.

Why not loading NewPX instead?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

% Different integral font
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}

\begin{document}

We say that a measurable function $f$ is of bounded mean oscillation if
\begin{equation*}
  \|f\|_{\mathrm{BMO}} := \sup_{B \text{ ball}} 
  \left( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \inf_{a\in\mathbb{R}} \int_B |f - a| \, d\mu \right) < \infty .
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output with `mathpazo` instead of NewPX

[image]

This is the output with `pxfonts` (only), which is really cramped:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need put `pxfonts` on the behind.

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

% Different integral font
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}

\begin{document}

We say that a measurable function $f$ is of bounded mean oscillation if
\begin{align*}
    \|f\|_{BMO} := \sup_{B \text{ ball}} \left( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \inf_{a\in\mathbb{R}} \int_B |f - a| \, d\mu \right) < \infty .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have removed all the error messages. Look into the code the done differences.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
We say that a measurable function $f$ is of bounded mean oscillation if
\begin{align*}
    \|f\|_{BMO} := \sup_{B \text{ ball}} \left( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \inf_{a\in\mathbb{R}} \int_B |f - a| \, d\mu \right) < \infty .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]